# How would I put a conditional statement into this JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

I would like to use a conditional statement in the code below. Basically, I want to do something like this:

`if (home page) insert 655, if (not home page) insert 391`

The body element of the home page has a class of `home` so I can use `.home #sidebar` to target the homepage sidebar.

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    var threshold = 655;
 if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= 655)
     jQuery('#sidebar').addClass('fixed');
  else
        jQuery('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
});
```

Here is my incorrect attempt at doing this (please don't laugh):

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    var threshold = if (is_home()) { 655 } else { 391 };
 if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= if (is_home()) { 655 } else { 391 })
     jQuery('#sidebar').addClass('fixed');
  else
        jQuery('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
});
```

Can someone help me out?

Edit: Here's the full code:

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Custom JS - All custom front-end jQuery

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Let's dance
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Fixed Sidebar
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    var threshold = jQuery(document.body).hasClass("home") ? 655 : 391;
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= threshold) {
        jQuery('#sidebar').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        jQuery('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
    }

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Pesky YouTube Videos
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    window.onload = function() {
        var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
        for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
            frames[i].src += "&wmode=opaque";
        }
    }

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Portfolio Filtering
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    if(jQuery().isotope) {

        $container = jQuery('#masonry');

        $container.imagesLoaded( function() {

            $container.isotope({
                itemSelector : '.item',
                masonry: {
                    columnWidth: $(document).width() > 1035 ? 240 : 320
                },
                getSortData: {

                    order: function($elem) {
                        return parseInt($elem.attr('data-order'));
                    }

                },
                sortBy: 'order'
            }, function() {

                // Isotope Chrome Fix   
                setTimeout(function () {        
                    jQuery('#masonry').isotope('reLayout'); 
                }, 1000);

            });


        }); 

        // filter items when filter link is clicked
        $container = jQuery('#masonry');

        jQuery('#filter li').click(function(){

            jQuery('#filter li').removeClass('active's);
            jQuery(this).addClass('active');

            var selector = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('data-filter');

            $container.isotope({ filter: selector });

            return false;

        });


    }

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  We've finished dancing!
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

});
```

Comment: what is `is_home()`? Is it the PHP/Wordpress function?

Comment: Are you asking how to detect the homepage?  Or asking something else?

Comment: @Will Yes, it is a WordPress function to detect the home page.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm asking how to change the numbers for only the home page. I want it to be `655` for the home page and `391` for all other pages.

Comment: OK, that's what my answer below does.

Comment: @Desi `is_home()` is a PHP function; Javascript can't use it. Handily, WordPress automatically spits out a class of 'home' on the body for the home page so  @jfriend00's answers should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `.hasClass()` to see if it's the homepage or not:

```
if (jQuery(document.body).hasClass("home")) {
    // home page here
} else {
    // not home page here
}
```

Of, if you just want to set your threshold value based on whether it's the homepage:

```
var threshold = jQuery(document.body).hasClass("home") ? 655 : 391;
if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= threshold) {
    jQuery('#sidebar').addClass('fixed');
} else {
    jQuery('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but this isn't working. I'm putting the second block of code in between `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` and `});`. Would that be the problem?

Comment: @Desi - there's a lot of potential reasons why your code might not be working.  I'd suggest you look in the browser error console or debug console and see what, if any, errors are getting reported.  If that doesn't show any errors, then post the ACTUAL code you are using so we can take a look.  There is nothing wrong with putting the code into a `jQuery(document).ready()` block.

Comment: Ok, I see. I posted the full code in the original post. If you can take a look, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Btw, currently I'm using your first block of code but inserted in between `script` tags in the footer. It's working perfectly. I'm just not sure why it doesn't work when I use the second block of code inside of a JavaScript file and called from the footer.

Answer (score 1):

You're misusing the ternary operator; no need for `if`

```
var threshold = (is_home()) ? 655 : 391;
if($(window).scrollTop() >= threshold)
    jQuery('#sidebar').addClass('fixed');
else
    jQuery('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
```

All the other answers already fully explain using ".hasClass", so I'm going to leave your "is_home()" in place.

Comment: I thought the OP was asking how to implement a conditional to check for the home page.

Comment: Yeah, I jumped the gun a bit there.  Not really much else I can change now without being a carbon-copy of everyone else :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the ternary conditional operator:

```
if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= ((is_home()) ? 655 : 391))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline condition. Replace this line

```
var threshold = if (is_home()) { 655 } else { 391 };
```

With this

```
var threshold = (is_home() ? 655 : 391);
```

Same gose for the other cases